# How to add application into icons?

Tags: c#, icons

I've been working on a application form, and it to be showable in the icons place, not in taskbar but like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpmis.jpg

I haven't found any related to adding the application to icons, simply because the search results was adding icons like icon.ico.

Comment: "Task Tray" is the term you're looking for.  The NotifyIcon control can help with that.

Comment: notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
notifyIcon.Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation;
notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Balloon Tip Title";
notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "Balloon Tip Text.";
notifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1000);

Didn't pop-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a NotifyIcon to your Form, then add the following code to Main_Load:

```
notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation;
notifyIcon1.Visible = true;

notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Hello";
notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
```

Then you'll want to add Click or DoubleClick event handlers, or ContextMenuStrip...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't get what you mean by Click events, but the way to add items, for example if I right click you have some text saying like unhide, exit or something like that?

Comment: Add a ContextMenuStrip to your Form, add Menu Items to it, then set your notifyIcon1 ContextMenuStrip property to your contextMenuStrip1.  When you right-click the NotifyIcon you should see menu.  You should be able to find tons of examples now that you know what to look for.